# cygwin cannot find my compiler from /cygdrive

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cygwin

I have a makefile which invokes my compiler from `/cygdrive/c/path/to/compiler`

when I'm in a cygwin shell, I can invoke it correctly, but from inside a makefile, the absolute path returns `"The system cannot find the file specified"`.

I don't understand why the makefile does not understand the absolute cygdrive path

edit*
In fact, any command with absolute path will fail.

```
/usr/bin/touch
```

will also return `"The system cannot find the file specified"`.

Comment: 1. Are you using the CC environment variable for specifying the path? 2. Does the path to your compiler contain spaces?

Comment: No spaces in path, in the makefile the compiler is refered as $(GCC), which is defined inside the makefile

Comment: My Cygwin installation of about a year ago doesn't have this problem, for what it's worth.  Since it seems to be a general Cygwin configuration issue, post if you can think of anything possibly relevant that might have been modified--user or system .bashrc, environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to use absolute paths to executables in Makefiles. You should be able to put this in the Makefile

```
CC=gcc
```

then as long as `gcc.exe` is on your `PATH` it will work. If you happen to be cross-compiling you could run this from the command line

```
make CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/install/rtmpdump/rtmpdump-dist-static.sh)

Comment: / is on my path, but it doesn't help